After override the tokenURI function, cannot get it on etherscan with error originalError code:3
I am working on a NFT project where I only allow those owners of NFT can get the tokenURI, but when I override the tokenURI function and tries to call it on etherscan sepolia to test, I get error.
The solidity code for overriding
Here is what etherscan sepolia shows me:
Error: execution reverted { "originalError": { "code": 3, "data": "0x946a1786", "message": "execution reverted" } }
Can anyone help?
I have try in the local environment, hardhat node. It works there but not work on the testnet.
Google a lot but those result with originalError code: 3 is not solved.
